# What does auxiliary prime mean?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm writing a paper right now, in which Sophie Germain's theorem is included.
Can anybody explain *auxiliary prime θ* to me?

Context:

Sophie Germain proved that the product $xyz$ must be divisible by $p^2$ if an auxiliary prime θ can be found such that two conditions are satisfied:

No two $p$th powers differ by one modulo θ; and
$p$ is itself not a $p$th power modulo θ.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to add way more context.

Comment: @pjs3 thanks mate :)

Comment: It would improve the question a lot, if you told the readers that you are discussing the cases of FLT studied by Sophie Germain. For example $xyz$ does not mean much at all unless it is stated that they form a putative counterexample to FLT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, auxiliary prime simply means a prime related to the inputs and conditions.  Given that $x,y,z,p$ satisfy

$$x^p + y^p = z^p$$

then $p^2$ divides $xyz$ **if** we can find a prime (the "auxiliary prime" $\theta$) such that

1. $p^n - p^m \ne 1 \text{ mod } \theta$ for all $m,n$, and
2. $p$ is itself not a $p$th power modulo $\theta$.